# Insert tag “series:” into Highcharts, from the response server JSON. Malformed JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

This is my second question about this problem:

I try to create a chart with Highcharts, but I can not fill the field "series" with the response returned from the server with PHP. The answer is in JSON format. The chart is not rendered, it goes white background. Thank you very much in advance. 
I paste her the 3 codes:

SERVER SIDE PHP:

```
$arr = array();
while ($row_RecordsetTabla = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetTabla))
{
    $fecha = $row_RecordsetTabla['fecha'];
    $hora = $row_RecordsetTabla['hora'];
    $estado = $row_RecordsetTabla['estado'];
    $arregloFecha = date_format(new DateTime($fecha),"Y,m,d");
    $arregloHora = date_format(new DateTime($hora),"H,i");
    $arr[] = array("Date.UTC(".$arregloFecha.",".$arregloHora.")", $estado);
}
$arr2[] = array('data' => $arr);
$json = json_encode($arr2);
echo str_replace('"', '', $json);
```

RESPONSE SERVER JSON:

```
[{data:[[Date.UTC(2014,03,27,12,00),2],[Date.UTC(2014,04,01,19,10),1],[Date.UTC(2014,04,01,15,44),1]]}]
```

CLIENT SIDE JAVASCRIPT HIGHCHARTS CODE:

```
$.get("mostrarStatsDispositivo.php", {idDispositivo:"2", numeroDispositivo:"hola"}, function(data){
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'divStatsDispositivo',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Gráfica de actividad'
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false,        
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                hour: '%H',
            }   
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: [ 'APAGADO', 'ACTIVO', 'ALARMA'],   
            title: {
                text: 'ESTADO'
            },
            min: 0
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'grafica',
            type : 'line',
            data : data[0].data //<-------thanks Barbara!
        }]
    });
});
```

The response JSON seems well formed..but dosn´t work...?¿  ....thanks!

EDIT: If i copy/paste the content of JSON in a variable, works fine. But i can´t put the value of JSON in a variable! ...doesn´t works! it´s posible?¿

FIXED!!!
Thanks Mr Jerko has detected (and solved) some errors in the code: 
There is an error in a line of PHP file:

I put:

```
$arr2[] = array('data' => $arr);
```

and correct line is:

```
$arr2 = array('data' => $arr);
```

Another error to create a JSON line, and another error to put the data on "series:". check the responde under!

Comment: Why are you doing `str_replace('"', '', $json)`?  Why are you invalidating the valid JSON that `json_encode` has created for you?

Comment: yes, you're right. JSON has created so wrong. I thought I had to remove the quotes for construct the JSON. Thanks for help!  I remove str_replace() from my code.

Answer (score 2):

change your php file to look like this:

```
$arr = array();

while ($row_RecordsetTabla = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetTabla))
{
    $fecha = $row_RecordsetTabla['fecha'];
    $hora = $row_RecordsetTabla['hora'];
    $estado = $row_RecordsetTabla['estado'];
    $arregloFecha = date_format(new DateTime($fecha),"Y-m-d");
    $arregloHora = date_format(new DateTime($hora),"H:i");
    $date = strtotime($arregloFecha . " " . $arregloHora) * 1000;
    $arr[] = array($date, floatval($estado));
}
$arr2 = array('data' => $arr);
echo json_encode($arr2);
```

your JSON was in incorrect format because when you return Date.UTC(2014,03,27,12,00) without quotes it breaks format of json so you should convert your times to microseconds in php before echoing it.

also you would probably need to change your javascript line to

```
data: data.data
```

Comment: Thanks Jerko! ...Thank you very much for responding. I tried to change the line of code, but the chart still does not work (white background). ¿Do you think the problem is how i pass the values ​​to Highcharts? ....sorry for my english!

Comment: I've put it in fiddle and I found bug, remove `enter code here` (javascript file, 3rd line) and it works :) here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pUpq8/2/ and btw you need to sort your input by dates.

Comment: Thanks! ...I do not have this line in my original code. It's been an error copying the file in question. 
If I copy the value of a variable from JSON in javascript works fine (as you put in the example). But it is to receive JSON from another file (the PHP server side) does not work. Thanks also for the help and dedication. if I put the value of 'data' (received the $ get function.) on the label "series:" directly, not working.

Comment: Woohoo! Jerko ... merci again. I changed the PHP file as you indicate me. But still not working. The Highchart not print the chart. Also, I appreciate your help and persistence! .... I owe you a beer

Comment: can you please give me json output? And does it even plot xAxis as yAxis?

Comment: yes! ...i paste JSON her: [{"data":[[1395921600000,2],[1396379400000,1],[1396367040000,1]]}]    "date / time" must be the xAxis and value of "state" must be the y-axis. I only need a "line" drawing on 3 "estats"(estado)

Comment: and one more question, do you have `header('Content-type: application/json');` in your php code?

Comment: header('Content-type: application/json');??? ...no
¿I put this line on top of my document PHP?

Comment: hm that's strange, made this on my server with all your files and it works fine, does you firebug or w/e you are using shows any error?

Comment: in your server works fine? ...OMG! ....thanks, i revise and separe the problem in a difirents files, for analize and after, i comment!  Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Wooohoo! Nice Jerko W. Tisler!